# Creating a pop-up image in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have searching this for a long time now,
Can anybody tell me how to create a pop-up image that opens when my app starts and the pop-up image should close when there is a click on the screen.
I tried using Dialog but could not get what i intended.

Comment: If the image can be full screen you can use an ordinary activity, and in the imageview's onclick just do finish() to close it.

Comment: can i set a on click listener on it?

Comment: Yes, use the setOnClickListener method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the JitPack repository to your build file:

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
  ...
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
implementation'com.github.chathuralakmal:AndroidImagePopup:1.2.2'
```

Create instance of the popup class and thats all !!

```
ImagePopup imagePopup = new ImagePopup(this); 

Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(this).build()); // Only needed if you 
are using Picasso

 final ImagePopup imagePopup = new ImagePopup(this);
 imagePopup.setWindowHeight(800); // Optional
 imagePopup.setWindowWidth(800); // Optional
 imagePopup.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  // Optional
 imagePopup.setFullScreen(true); // Optional
 imagePopup.setHideCloseIcon(true);  // Optional
 imagePopup.setImageOnClickClose(true);  // Optional

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

 imagePopup.initiatePopup(imageView.getDrawable()); // Load Image from Drawable


 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      /** Initiate Popup view **/
   imagePopup.viewPopup();

  }
 });
```